# One-to-one correspondence between n-edge-colourings of $K_{n,n}$ and Latin squares

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, bipartite-graphs, latin-square

I need help with this. I don't know how to do this (especially case b) ).

a) An $n \times n$ array $A = (a_{ij})$, whose entries are taken from some set $S$ of $n$ symbols, is called a Latin square of order $n$ if each symbol appears precisely once in each row and precisely once in each column of $A$. Show that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $n$-edge-colourings of  $K_{n,n}$ in colours $1, 2, \dots , n$ and Latin squares of order $n$ in symbols $1, 2, \dots, n$.

b) Deduce from the (below) Theorem the following assertion, a special case of a conjecture due to J. Dinitz.

For $1 \leq i\leq j \leq n$, let $S_{ij}$ be a set of $n$ elements. Then there exists a Latin square $A = (a_{ij})$ of order $n$ using a set $S$ of $n$ symbols such that $a_{ij} \in S_{ij} \cap S$, $1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$.

**Theorem:** Every simple bipartite graph $G$ is $\Delta$-list-edge-colourable.

Comment: I don't understand the assertion in part (b). Are $S_{ij}$ and $a_{ij}$ only defined for $i\le j$? And what if the sets $S_{ij}$ happen to be pairwise disjoint, so that the elements $a_{ij}$ are pairwise distinct? What is the "set $S$ of $n$ symbols" supposed to be in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your answer to (a) formalized the bijection illustrated below:

[image]

Basically, the symbol $s$ in cell $(a,b)$ maps to the edge $\text{row}_a \text{col}_b$, say, of color $s$.

For the second part, it's the same idea with "symbol"/"color" replaced by "list".

[image]

The list $L$ assigned to cell $(a,b)$ maps to the edge $\text{row}_a \text{col}_b$ which is also assigned the list $L$.  The theorem implies a $\Delta$-list-edge-coloring exists, which we convert back to give a $n \times n$ matrix which we can show has no repeated symbols in the rows and columns.

As bof points out, however, the statement of the [Dinitz <strike>Conjecture</strike> Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitz_conjecture) is incorrect.  I.e., it doesn't guarantee a Latin square, just no repeats in rows/columns (a generalization of a Latin square).